# arrange html div tag to empty area in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have rendered html div tags with three different size(Small,Large,Medium) in an order like below
[image]

my problem is after rendering large tile the remaining small tiles will be coming under large tile by creating white spaces. I need to automatically move the below small tiles to the white spaces when loading div tags. How can I resolve my problem by using CSS? is this default behaviour of css?

**Medium Tile CSS**

```
.clsMediumWidget{
    width: 39.5%;
    height: 245px;
    background-color: #f6f6f8;
    border: 0.2em solid #E9E9E9;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

**Small Tile class**

```
.clsSmallWidget{
    width: 19.3%;
    height: 245px;
    background-color: #f6f6f8;
    border: 0.2em solid #E9E9E9;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

**Large Tile CSS**

```
.clsLargeWidget {
width: 39.5%;
height: 494px;
background-color: #f6f6f8;
border: 0.2em solid #E9E9E9;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is what you are looking for

Comment: We need to see the code. Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: now i am arranging the div by using float left. i have to move the last three small tiles to the white space that i have marked in the picture

Comment: This is indeed default behavior of CSS when using float: left. Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could look into flexbox. Display: table-cell might also get you quite far, but I'm not too sure about the details.

Comment: ok.let me post my CSS also

Comment: Instead of using a `Javascript` solution, you could also accomplish this using `CSS3`, specifically `columns` - http://jsfiddle.net/tEhfJ/ It depends if you need to support older browsers or not.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the css

Comment: | am not looking for Masonry.I need to solve by using Css or javascript

Comment: Masonry (or it's successor Isotope isotope.metafizzy.co) also solves this by using javascript. Check this CSS only one too http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

Comment: float:left  and display:inline-block try useing such type of css

Comment: I have tried a sample by using Masonry but the order of tile is changed. So masonry is not a complete solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some reason you don't want to do this, it should solve the problem mentioned.

**Large Tile CSS**

```
float: right;
```

[**Fiddle Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhhJ6/)

Comment: answer is good but the problem is the size is dynamic. Some time the second will be large. we can't predict which tile type is also I have load these tiles in an accordion each section of accordion contains these group of tiles

Comment: I see. I can't think of a pure CSS solution for this issue. My 1st recommendation would be convincing the powers that be to let you make all the tiles the same height. Next idea is combining two small tiles into one large whenever or if possible. Beyond that I'd say you're looking at some JavaScript/jquery to force the various tile sizes where you want them.

Comment: if the height is same it will work fine but I can't comprise with the height. In my application user can resize the tiles,re arrange the tiles and also can save the order in the db. everything is working fine but this is the only problem I am facing. I know we can't fix with pure CSS. did you have any idea for fixing this issue?

Comment: I was thinking you could use javascript to make sure large tiles were always the first elements inside the accordion. frankly, however, learning that you plan to allow users to resize and rearrange the tiles makes me wonder why in the world you wouldn't just start with all the same height? or just cascade the tiles one on top of another using z-index and a 20px x,y offset. Once a user gets their paws on the tiles I doubt things will be looking pretty anyway unless you're constraining them somehow.

Comment: actually this is the requirement. If the Large tile is first everything works fine.So there is no point of re arranging the tiles. Actually now  I am trying to solve this by using http://masonjs.com/.